# Pandas's .to_string(index=True) not following documentation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print the value of one column if the value of another column matches some criteria. In the example below, I want to print the name of the student if their score is 5. (For simplicity, there is only one student in the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['name'] = ['jane']
df['score'] = [5]
```

When I try to print the name using the most simple solution, I get a bunch of stuff other than just the name:

```
In [62]:

print(df['name'][df['score'] == 5])
0    jane
Name: name, dtype: object
```

When I try to use the .to_string function, I still get the index number:

```
In [60]:

print(df['name'][df['score'] == 5].to_string())
Out[60]:
[0    jane
 Name: name, dtype: object]
```

Finally, I looked at the .to_string() [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) and found this:

> index : bool, optional whether to print index (row) labels, default
>   True

However, when I try to use .to_string(index=False), I get an error:

```
In [64]:

df['name'][df['score'] == 5].to_string(index = False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4ed8cfe4b098> in <module>()
----> 6 df['name'][df['score'] == 5].to_string(index = False)

TypeError: to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation you linked to is for `DataFrame.to_string`, but you are calling `to_string` on a Series (since you start by selecting one column with `df['name']`).  [The documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.to_string.html) for `Series.to_string` shows that it doesn't accept an `index` argument.

One could argue that maybe it should have one, but the behavior is at least consistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
df['name'][df['score'] == 5][0]
```

returns a *[Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)* of strings. If you want to print all the strings in the *Series*, you should iterate it just like you would iterate a list or tuple.

Therefore, if you want to print the names of all the students whose score is 5:

```
for student in df['name'][df['score'] == 5]:
    print(student)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work as you prefer:

```
    In [10]:
    print(df[df['score'] == 5][['score','name']].to_string(columns=['name'],header=False,index=False))
    Out[10]:
     jane
```